# rails 3, in link_to how specify target AND optional url params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I got extra url params working fine with my link_to , but cannot figure out how to make the link open into a a new window or tab

I tried :target => "_blank" in several places, but it always throws a syntax error

here's what I have before specifying a target:

```
= link_to "click here", :controller=>"widget", :action=>"mypage", :extraparam => "foobar"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
link_to "click here", { :controller=>"widget", :action=>"mypage", :extraparam => "foobar" }, :target => "_blank"
```

Comment: Or for a "standard" link, `link_to "click here", "http://what.ever/foo.html", :target => "_blank"`